# Constructor calling only once in React Native

Tags: android, react-native, navigation

Hi i am new to React native, i used Stack Navigation for the navigation purpose i want to know the reason why constructor is not called again when i go back from screen 2 to screen 1. is there any way to do that?

this is the constructor for Screen 1:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    alert("Hello Constructor");
}
```

And this is the button i have to goBack to Screen 1

```
  <Button
          onPress={() => goBack()}
          title="Go back from this HomeScreen"
        />
```

Comment: Screen 1 is already mounted. It is not unmounted when you navigate forward to the next screen. Constructor is invoked when a new instance of  a class is generated

Comment: @Hariks actually i have to call a service repeatedly in order to check for updated records on screen 1. i used setInterval for that and cleared that interval on the button which takes me to the second screen. But when i goback from second screen to first my interval does not starts again. can you help me out with that?

Comment: A simple workaround is to pass a function as a prop to screen 2 from screen 1. Write your updating code in that function and call that function from screen 2 when you navigate back to screen 1

Comment: Or if you are using redux, you can set a global flag to update data and use componentWillReceiveProps to check the flag in Screen 1 to kick-start your updating code.

Comment: seems legit, i will surely try that. thanks man.